# using Android 5.0 canvas drawCircle with shadow in Translucent theme is weired

Tags: android, imageview, shadow

I am making an Activity with transparent theme

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
```

and using circle ImageView with shadow in LinearLayout with background #FFFFFFFF , in the Circle ImageView Class need to use

```
setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

then the shadow work fine in Android 4.x, but in Android 5.x it looks like the picture, the square block disappear

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jtKG.jpg

Anyone know what is going in Android 5.X ?
does this have any solution ?

Comment: I faced same issue some days ago, may I know which custom view you are using for circle image..

Comment: @CapDroid I did it by my self, with the function what I need, like shadow, board and some parameters. Did you solve this issue?

Comment: I just given background color to ImageView. you can also try.

Comment: @CapDroid Thank you but I want the background be a picture, maybe someone know how to solve that....

Comment: I also tried to find out solution but I can't able to find out. finally I go for background approach.